Is it possible to actually change a function signature at runtime? (and have it enforced)
I want to dynamically change a function's signature. Here's my code:
from inspect import getfullargspec, signature
from functools import wraps

def mock(sign):
    def deco(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            print('wrap', args, kwargs)
        wrap.__signature__ = signature(sign)
        return wrap
    return deco

def test(a, b):
    print(a, b)

@mock(test)
def func(c):
    print(c)

print(getfullargspec(func)) # -> FullArgSpec(args=['a', 'b'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})

func(1) # -> wrap (1,) {}


According the program output, the signature is changed successfully. However, supplying an input that doesn't fit the signature goes through with no Exceptions, contrary to what I would expect. Is there a way to make sure the signature is automatically enforced?

You did not change the signature. You only changed (or created) the informative __signature__ attribute. The signature of wrap remains *args, **kwargs.

In CPython, truly altering the signature would likely require modifying the underlying code object, as the number of parameters affects the numbering of all local variables, altering how they are accessed in byte code.

If you genuinely managed to change wrap's signature, it would no longer take *args or **kwargs arguments, so that print('wrap', args, kwargs) line would be attempting to read variables that no longer exist.
